# Block sound in HTML page when it loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need some help because tthe chat sound when the user writes is being played when i refresh/load the page.

I need to know if it's possible make it not play only when the page is loaded.

**Code in Context**

```
var audioElement5 = document.createElement('audio');
audioElement5.setAttribute('src', 'sounds/chat.wav');   
audioElement5.volume=1.0;
```

If i place the file where the code is script.js in the *head* section this plays the sound, if i place it above the place where I'm creating the sounds they will play one when the user writes something but when i load the page i get these following errors:

> uncaught referenceerror audioElement5 is not defined  (anonymous function)

So the solution that i need is to not play the sound when the html is loading or something similar to that.

I also tested like this:

beforemy body i set this:

```
<script>

            audioElement5.muted = true;
</script>
```

and above my footer this:

```
  <script>

            audioElement5.muted = false;
</script>
```

but didn't work.

Comment: So when do you want it to play?

Comment: `audioElement5.volume=1.0;` is this allowed? Are you setting autoplay or autostart somewhere?

Comment: @gcampbell Only when the users write in the chat but that is already working.

Comment: @putvande well if i lower it the sound will be lower so i think yes tht is possible

Comment: i just want like mute the sound when the page is loading and unmute the sound when the page is loaded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move your code to windows onload function, so it will trigger only when page is loaded....

```
windows.onload = function(){
  // move your code here
}
```

OR

you can place your code in a function like:

```
function loadAudio(){
   // your code
}
```

and call it before /body

```
<script>loadAudio();</script>
</body>
```

Hope this helps?

Comment: `window` not `windows` :)

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can do:

```
function loadAudio() {
// Your javascript code here.
}

$(document).ready(function() {
loadAudio();
});
```